# everit json schema validator ( java ) if/then/else not validating as expected under 1.5.1 version

Tags: java, json, maven, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to use if/then/else to validate the json but the if/else/part is not validating as expected.
When i compare "example.json" with "parentSchema.json" file.. it is suppose to throw me an error as i'm not providing "name" in the file.. but it is not throwing me any error and validating successfully.

Tried multiple values and multiple scenarios, including allOf etc. Tried validating my schemas in different websites (online editors), It is executing properly over there and throwing me error as expected but not in my code. It will be really helpful if someone could help me out.

below is my main class code. `

```
import org.everit.json.schema.Schema;
import org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class TestingJsonSchema {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(
                new JSONTokener(TestingJsonSchema.class.getResourceAsStream("/parentSchema.json")));
        JSONObject jsonSubject = new JSONObject(
                new JSONTokener(TestingJsonSchema.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.json")));

        //validateSchema
        try{
            Schema schemaValidator = SchemaLoader.load((jsonSchema));
            schemaValidator.validate(jsonSubject);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(" message is :"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

`

below is my pom.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

below is my parent json file "parentSchema.json".

```
   {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "enum": ["Russia", "Canada"]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { "id": { "const" : "Russia" }}
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["name"]
  },
  "else": {
    "required": ["price"]
  }
}
```

below is my actual json to be validated "example.json".

```
{
  "id": "Russia",
  "price": 10.50
}
```

It should throw me an error as i'm not sending "name" but it is validating successfully as if the "IF/THEN/ELSE" block never got executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an old version of `org.everit.json.schema`.  Evidently version 1.5.1 doesn't support the `if`-`then`-`else` construct.

The fix is to edit your `pom.xml` and replace

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

with

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.everit-org.json-schema</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and also add the following repository to the `<repositories>` element of your `pom.xml` file.  (If the `<repositories>` element doesn't exist, create it.)

```xml
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
```

See also the [Maven installation](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema#maven-installation) section of the project's README.

I made this change to your project, ran it and it generated the following output:

```
 message is :#: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. It actually worked. I was able to get the output as desired.